# Detect number of processes running with the same name

Tags: powershell, process, instances

Any ideas of how to write a function that returns the number of instances of a process is running?

Perhaps something like this?

```
function numInstances([string]$process)
{
    $i = 0
    while(<we can get a new process with name $process>)
    {
        $i++
    }

    return $i
}
```

Edit: Started to write a function... It works for a single instance but it goes into an infinite loop if more than one instance is running:

```
function numInstances([string]$process)
{
$i = 0
$ids = @()
while(((get-process $process) | where {$ids -notcontains $_.ID}) -ne $null)
    {
    $ids += (get-process $process).ID
    $i++
    }

return $i
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
function numInstances([string]$process)
{
    @(get-process -ea silentlycontinue $process).count
}
```

**EDIT**: added the silently continue and array cast to work with zero and one processes.

Comment: Never thought it could be so simple!

Comment: I think this does not work well for 0 and 1 instance. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @roman good point - i like that you casted the response as an array

Comment: @Jack - PowerShell rocks with a short Ballard ;-)

Answer (score 10):

This works for me:

```
function numInstances([string]$process)
{
    @(Get-Process $process -ErrorAction 0).Count
}

# 0
numInstances notepad

# 1
Start-Process notepad
numInstances notepad

# many
Start-Process notepad
numInstances notepad
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
```

Though it is simple there are two important points in this solution: 1) use `-ErrorAction 0` (0 is the same as `SilentlyContinue`), so that it works well when there are no specified processes; 2) use the array operator `@()` so that it works when there is a single process instance.

Answer (score 7):

Its much easier to use the built-in cmdlet group-object:

```
 get-process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice one-liner : `(ps).count`

Comment: OP asked about same name process count. How does this help?

Comment: If you need the same process count you can use argument -Name, eg. `(ps -Name 'Wmi*').count`

Answer (score 3):

(Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Chrome'}).count

This will return you the number of processes with same name running. you can add filters to further format your data.